# Spring Boot: Turn off the console logs to the file '/var/log/app.log'

Tags: spring-boot, logback

I'm using the Spring Boot launch script (for [Spring Boot on Linux](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.RC1/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-service)) and it asks for a [LOG_FOLDER](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.RC1/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-script-customization) property.

I do not want to make use of this property, because logging is already being done by logback.xml. We now end up having double log files. (One in the location set by logback.xml and /var/log/app.log, set as default by the launch script)

How can I get rid off this double log file: var/log/app.log?

Answer (score 2):

With the default script, you cannot switch off logging. The only way would be to make a copy of the script and modify it according to your needs. But, you can change the location of the default log folder.

You can customize the behaviour of the launch script by creating the `<yourAppName>.conf` file. The file is expected next to the jar file and have the same name but suffixed with .conf rather than .jar. Add the following line in it to change the log file location:

```
LOG_FOLDER=/custom/log/folder
```

Comment: So you are forced to use console logging if you use the script?

Comment: You are forced to have a log file to write the console logs.